# striping elements from string inside of list(python)

Tags: python, string, loops

I am having a data set which is from MongoDB and looks like:

```
info=['[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":[{"another_key":"another_value"}]}]',
'[{"key1":"valuex","key2":"valuex","key3":[{"another_keyx":"another_valuex"}]}]',
'[{"key_1":"valuex","key2":"valuex","key3":[{"keyx":"valuex"}]}]']
```

Its all in string so I am trying to use this method:

```
city=[]
    for index, row in csv.iterrows():
    
    if 'key1' in str(row['ip_info']):
        city.append() #the value of key1 # some logic I don't know how to code
                       # but it is like if we find "key1" in this string then slice a portion which start from key1": and end at ",
    else:
        city.append(0)
```

Expected output need to be like:

```
city=["value1","valuex",0]
```

I am trying to implement the logic as when "key1" is found in string then we will slice the string from "key1":(as starting point) and end at ",(which is right after the value of that key, so that we can get what's between those starting and ending points.

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: i need to pull the value of specific keys in a list.. for example there is key1 in every element of the main list so I am trying to pull the value of key1 from every element...but also the length of the extracted list need to match the no. of elements of original list so I am putting a 0 in case the key1 is not available in any element of main list

Comment: Expected output please. It's not easy to understand when explanation is verbose

Comment: Sir I just added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
city = []

for element in info:
    inner_dict = eval(element)[0]
    if "key1" in inner_dict.keys():
        city.append(inner_dict["key1"])
    else:
        city.append(0)

print(city)

# OUTPUT:
# ['value1', 'valuex', 0]
```

Comment: I really appreciate this but the source code will always throw a string ...like if you look in code it is like[["string"],["string"],["string"]]

Comment: so I need to solve the problem by string methods...dictionaries are inside the string in op results so dictionary functions will not work in this data

Comment: yes i understand that, which is why ive used eval here. It will evaluate the contents inside the string. In this case you have a dictionary inside a string

Comment: Let me get this straight... the info variable you have put on the question isnt the one you will be working on?

Comment: it is of almost same structure but much lengthy

Comment: like there are dictionaries in values of key which are already values of another keys....

Comment: Can you try this code on your data? replace info with whatever you are using as an input and replace the key1 as well if its different. If it throws an error please share the exact data you are using. I tried this on info data you had sent and it gives the exact output you expected.

Comment: Yes I tried but it is giving error (NameError: name 'false' is not defined) on- inner_dict = eval(element)[0] ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230865/discussion-between-neeraj-and-yatin-hasija).

Comment: I can even share a few elements from original list but they will not fit in this comment